# Highly available and load balanced ActiveMQ cluster

Tags: activemq-classic

Please be aware that I am a relative newbie to ActiveMQ.

I am currently working with a small cluster of ActiveMQ (version 5.15.x) nodes (< 5).  I recently experimented with setting up the configuration to use "Shared File System Master Slave" with kahadb, in order to provide high availability to the cluster.

Having done so and seeing how it operates, I'm now considering whether this configuration provides the level of throughput required for both consumers/producers, as only one broker's ports are available at one time.

My question is basically two part.  First, does it make sense to configure the cluster as highly available AND load balanced (through Network of Brokers)?  Second, is the above even technically viable, or do I need to review my design consideration to favor one aspect over the other?

Answer (score 1):

I had some discussions with the ActiveMQ maintainers in IRC on this topic a few months back.

It seems that they would recommend using [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/) instead of ActiveMQ 5.

Artemis has a HA solution:

- https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html
- https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/ha.html

The idea is to use [Data Replication](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/ha.html#data-replication) to allow for failover, etc:

> When using replication, the live and the backup servers do not share the same data directories, all data synchronization is done over the network. Therefore all (persistent) data received by the live server will be duplicated to the backup.

And, I think you want to have at least 3 nodes (or some odd number) to [avoid issues with split brain during network partitions](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/network-isolation.html).

---

It seems like Artemis can mostly be used as a drop-in replacement for ActiveMQ; it can still speak the [OpenWire](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/openwire.html) protocol, etc.

However, I haven't actually tried this yet, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for responding @pioto.  I'll have to pass the idea of Artemis to my architect, as we have to get approval to use any new components of our infrastructure.  I do agree with the odd number of nodes.  With that being said, it seems like I should be able to configure the bridges to the other brokers concurrently just by using different port numbers in the network configuration without affecting the transport listener.